# Connecting to Pocket API with R

Tags: r

I'm trying to connect to the Pocket API via R. I can do this easily by running a POST request in json format like this:

URL: http://getpocket.com/v3/get

```
POST /v3/get HTTP/1.1  
Host: getpocket.com  
Content-Type: application/json  

{"consumer_key":"xxx-xxxxx",  
"access_token":"aaaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"}
```

In R I tried using the POST function in the *httr* package, but I wasn't able to figure out how to pass the correct parameters:

```
library(rjson); library(httr)
the_url <- "https://getpocket.com/v3/get"
the_body <- toJSON(list(consumer_key = "xxx-xxxxx", access_token="aaaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa"))
results <- POST(url=the_url, encode="json", body=the_body)
```

I always get the status "400 Bad Request". I know the example is not reproducible, but for security reasons I'd rather not share the `consumer_key` and `access_token` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your `access_token` is a good one? If so, I think you just need to change to

```
url <- "https://getpocket.com/v3/get"
body <- list(consumer_key = "xxx-xxxxx", access_token="aaaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa")
results <- POST(url, body = body)
content(results)
```

Comment: Scott. your solution worked just fine. The access token was correct, but I was making things more complicated than need be. Thank you.